# Python not reading string a second time

Tags: python, string, adventure

I'm writing a text adventure (does anyone remember [Zork](https://it.wikipedia.org/wiki/Zork)?), and I'm having troubles with this code:

```python
from random import randint

def prompt():
    action = input(">>> ").lower()
    if action == "exit":
        quit()
    elif action == "save":
        save()
    else:
        return action

def action_error(custom=False):
    if custom != False:
        print(custom)
    else:
        phrases = ["A bunch", "of funny", "error phrases"]
        print(phrases[randint(1, len(phrases)-1)])
    return prompt()

action = prompt()
while True:
    print(action) #Debugging purposes
    if action.find("switch") != -1:
        if action.find("light") != -1:
            second_room() #Story continues
        else:
            action = action_error("What do you want to switch?")
    action = action_error()
```

The matter is that if I enter a string that contains "switch", the next input is not picked up.

Also, anyone has better ways to parse verb-noun strings like "switch the light", "open the door" or "look around"/"look at OBJECT"?

Comment: I am not sure if I understand well, but isn't `if "switch" in action` is what you think of?

Comment: Let's see if I understand. Your intended behavior is: user enters "switch". game prints "What do you want to switch?". User enters "light". Game proceeds to second room. Right? But at the moment, if the user enters "switch" and then "light", it doesn't work as expected?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First of all I noticed that if you enter switch twice the second time it's caught as an error by your program.
I think the problem lies at the end of the action_error function where you assign the return value to prompt(), so the input get consumed too early.

A possible fix would be:

```
def action_error(custom=False):
    if custom != False:
        print(custom)
    else:
        phrases = ["A bunch", "of funny", "error phrases"]
        print(phrases[randint(1, len(phrases)-1)])

while True:
    action = prompt()
    print(action) #Debugging purposes
    if action.find("switch") != -1:
        if action.find("light") != -1:
            second_room() #Story continues
        else:
            action_error("What do you want to switch?")
    else:
        action_error()
```

So no return value for action_error() and direct assignment at the beginning of the while loop.

Answer (score 0):

How about, in the case of a partially entered compound action, you concatenate the new input to the old one? Then "switch" becomes "switch light", and both of your conditionals will pass.

```
action = prompt()
while True:
    print(action) #Debugging purposes
    if action.find("switch") != -1:
        if action.find("light") != -1:
            second_room() #Story continues
        else:
            action = action + " " + action_error("What do you want to switch?")
            continue
    action = action_error()
```

---

Bonus style suggestions:

- replace `a.find("b") != -1` with `"b" in a`
- use `random.choice(phrases)` instead of `phrases[randint(1, len(phrases)-1)]`

Comment: the intended behavior is answering "What do you want to switch?" if the user just enters "switch", and proceed to the second room if he enters something like "switch light" or "switch on the light". The main idea is 'grepping' through the input and try to guess what the user meant.

Comment: Ah, in that case you probably need a `continue` statement to skip the bottom-most `action_error()` call. Edited.